# Return TOP unique and 'not already returned' rows from SQL based on different criterias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL data table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------+------+----------+
| employee_id |    date    | type | eligible |
+-------------+------------+------+----------+
|           1 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           2 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           3 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           4 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           5 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           6 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           1 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           2 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           3 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           4 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           5 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           6 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
+-------------+------------+------+----------+
```

I want to return the top 3 **unique** employee ID rows based on the type. So essentially, if the `employee_id` is returned for `type = 1` then skip this `employee_id` until it gets to one that hasn't already been returned.

The results should look like this:

```
+-------------+------------+------+----------+
| employee_id |    date    | type | eligible |
+-------------+------------+------+----------+
|           1 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           2 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           3 | 17/11/2019 |    1 | TRUE     |
|           4 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           5 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
|           6 | 17/11/2019 |    2 | TRUE     |
+-------------+------------+------+----------+
```

I have tried using a `UNION` for the two queries, and a `WITH` statement to combine the two `SELECT TOP 3` statements, but everything I have done, just returns `employee_id` 1,2,3,1,2,3 as the statement seemingly can't tell it's already been selected in the other dataset.

Comment: How many types do you have?  Do employees always have all types?

Comment: Two types - employees always have a type as it defaults to 1 if it doesn't have 2 if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated problem.  If you have two sets:

```
with t1 as (
      select top (3) t.*
      from t
      where type = 1
      order by employee_id
     )
select t12.*
from ((select t1.*
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select top (3) t2.*
       from t t2
       where type = 2 and
             not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id)
       order by employee_id
      )
     ) t12;
```

This works for the data you have provided.  However, it might not generalize to all situations.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff - I have tried this on the dataset, and limited to the example columns I provided, but it doesn't seem to return the `TOP 3` - it returns everything with some entries removed.

Comment: @RazorKillBen . . . The `TOP (3)` is pretty explicit in the subqueries.  I don't see how more than three rows could be returned per type.

Comment: Is it possible the `from ((select t1.* from t1` should be `from((select top (3) t1.* from t1`?

Comment: @RazorKillBen . . . No.  `t1` already has `select top (3)` when it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select employee_id, date, type, eligible from (select employee_id, date, type, eligible,
rank() over (partition by type order by employee_id) as rank from employee) rs 
where 1=(case when type =1 and rank<=3 then 1 when type = 2 and rank>3 then 1 end)
```